# Database overwritten in Android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

what i am doing is xml parsing and saving it to the database, but for the 1st time it was ok but now its overwriting same database again and again. How can i put a check that when new data come in xml then only write to database otherwise not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need to manually handle such things there are noway for the Android to determined whatever your data changed or not.

you need to write some logic to know if the data changed or not !

Answer (score 0):

To check new data come in xml then only write to database otherwise not you can race it to **logcat** to view.